# FTP across multiple clients like FileZilla not working

Tags: ftp, file-transfer

I'm not sure if this is the right place for this, I hope so!

I'm trying to use FileZilla to connect to a few different websites I developed awhile back.  It connects sometimes, It's usually pretty slow but I can browse directories.  Then when uploading several files, after a couple are successfull, I get the following error.

```
Error:  GnuTLS error -110: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
Status: Server did not properly shut down TLS connection
Error:  The data connection could not be established: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted
```

I tried different Encryption settings but none of them work good, I can always connect but then get an error.  I even have it set to Plain FTP but then after it connects (which is really slow) I try to upload load or do much and get this error...

```
The data connection could not be established: ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server
```

What is weird is it is doing this across multiple different websites on multiple webservers.  I also have the same issue on a couple different computers I tested.  I have also used multiple FTP client like FileZilla and WinSCP with the same results.  Could the issue be something with my home network?

I've used this same method to FTP into websites for years so I'm really confused!

Please Help!

Comment: ask the administrator of the server, if fail2ban I. e. has banned you, the question is, do you use sftp, ftp or ftps... you should have a good read of [ask] and update the question afterwards

Comment: @djdomi What are you even talking about?  Maybe you should read how to make a good comment somewhere.  It clearly states in the question how I'm trying to connect, "I even have it set to Plain FTP"